# Building a database table watcher

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows-services, signalr, watch

I need the ability to watch a table for changes and perform some actions when new records are added.

Basically what I'm trying to do is:

- Watch a table for new records.
- When a new record has been added,
  push a message to all connected users via SignalR.

Is a Windows Service the best solution for this?

Comment: why not have a trigger in the DB do that for you?

Comment: Could I call a controller and/or a method in my MVC application from a trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an insert trigger that writes to another table like `NewData` or something.  You could then create a service (a windows service would be fine), that periodically checked the `NewData` table for writes.  After you process each row in `NewData`, you could delete the row, and wait for the next one.

Now if you're trying to notify your logged in users, you'll have to either involve some AJAX or continually refreshing functionality in the page to see what's happening on the server side.

Comment: Dan, I was leaning towards the windows service. As for notifying logged in users, I was going to attempt to use SignalR.

Answer (score 1):

a terrible idea is to create a CLR trigger that calls your web service directly.
i have done this before in a pinch and it works, it just isn't super fast or good practice.
but it works.